# I get a corrupted file when opening an email attachment sent with the PHP version of SendGrid mail

Tags: php, attachment, sendgrid, corrupt

I am trying to send attachments with SendGrid through PHP, but keep getting a corrupted file error when I open the attachment.  The error message "We're sorry. We can't open 'file.docx' because we found a problem with its contents" and when I click on the details of the error I see "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"

My code looks like the below:

```
$sendGridLoginInfo = $contactViaEmail->getSendGridLoginInfo();    
        $sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendGridLoginInfo['Username'], $sendGridLoginInfo['Password']);    
        $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
        //Add the tracker args
        $mail->addUniqueArgument("EmailID", $emailID);
        $mail->addUniqueArgument("EmailGroupID", $emailGroupID);
        /*
        *    INSERT THE SUBSITUTIONS FOR SEND GRID
        */
        foreach ($availableSubstitutions as $availableSubstitution)
        {
            $mail->addSubstitution("[[" . $availableSubstitution . "]]", $substitutions[$availableSubstitution]);
        }

        /*
        *    ADD EACH EMAIL AS A NEW ADD TO
        *    This makes it BCC (because each person gets their own copy) and each person gets their own individualized email.
        */
        foreach ($emailInfo['SendToEmailAddress'] as $toEmail)
        {


            if ($sendToLoggedInUser)
            {
                $mail->addTo($adminEmailAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                $mail->addTo($toEmail);
            }
            $trashCount++;
        }

        //Set the subject
        $mail->setSubject($emailInfo['EmailSubject']);

        //Instantiate the HTML Purifier (for removing the html)
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('HTML', 'Allowed', '');
        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
        $mail->setText($purifier->purify($emailBody));
        $mail->setHtml($emailBody);

        if ($emailInfo['AttachmentID'])
        {
            $sql = "SELECT
                        AttachmentPath
                    FROM
                        EmailAttachments
                    WHERE
                        EmailAttachments.AttachmentID = :attachmentID";    
            if ($query = $pdoLink->prepare($sql))
            {
                $bindValues = array();
                $bindValues[":attachmentID"] = $emailInfo['AttachmentID'];

                if ($query->execute($bindValues))
                {
                    if ($row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $attachment = "";
                        $mail->addAttachment($sitedb . $row['AttachmentPath']);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }




        if ($sendToLoggedInUser)
        {
            $mail->setFrom($adminEmailAddress);
            $mail->setReplyTo($adminEmailAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            $mail->setFrom($emailInfo['FromAddress']);
            $mail->setReplyTo($emailInfo['ReplyTo']);
        }            
        $mail->setFromName($emailInfo['FromName']);

        $sendgrid->web->send($mail);
```

I've played with the content type and everything else that I can think of and just cannot find out what is causing the attachments to be corrupted.

Comment: What does `var_dump($sitedb . $row['AttachmentPath']);` output? Can you verify that it's a valid path?

Comment: It outputs the path and file name: /emailattachments/testemail2017060709374000000028075.docx

Comment: The path and file name are both correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an attachment object to add an attachment, you can't use the path directly like you are. SendGrid requires files to be sent as base64 encoded strings.

You'll need to create the attachment object, you could do this as a method:

```
public function getAttachment($path) 
{
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        return false;
    }

    $attachment = new SendGrid\Attachment;
    $attachment->setContent(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))); 
    $attachment->setType(mime_content_type($path));
    $attachment->setFilename(basename($path));
    $attachment->setDisposition('attachment');
    return $attachment;
}
```

Then add it to your email:

```
$attachment = $this->getAttachment($sitedb . $row['AttachmentPath']);
if ($attachment instanceof SendGrid\Attachment) {
    $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
}
```

Comment: I don't have an Attachment class. Do you know I can obtain the php file with that class?

Comment: Based on your example it looks like you're using [sendgrid-php 3.2.0](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases/tag/v3.2.0) or lower which uses SendGrid API v2 which should have the class outlined in my post. It should be in the same place `SendGrid\Mail` is coming from. You should really upgrade to v3 but it requires a rewrite of your mail class to support personalisation.

Comment: Can you send me that class? I don't have that class unfortunately

Comment: You can download it directly from GitHub: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases/tag/v3.2.0 this one is for SendGrid API v2 and should be compatible with your code.

Comment: It looks like I am on version 1.0.5. Is there a way to do this using version 1.0.5?

Comment: This also started happening after upgrading to PHP 5.6 FYI

Comment: The library you’re using may contain functionality that is [incompatible with 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php). Try upgrading to a newer version of sendgrid-php.